# Ember - Updating ember record with new ID on PUT request

Tags: api, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I have a backend that will create a new resource on a `PUT` request if the requested resource is not found. I.E...

1. Make a `PUT` request to `/api/v1/person/1/`
2. For one reason or another person with id 1 has been deleted from server
3. Server creates new person record with id 2

Now in my case these requests are being triggered from an Ember app. When I try to update a person in the Ember store with id 1 and it is deleted on the server, I get - `An adapter cannot assign a new id to a record that already has an id.`

The server has returned a new person record with id 2 and Ember errors trying to apply it to the model it has in it's store with id of 1.

So far I am overriding the `updateId` method of `DS.Store`:

```
export default DS.Store.extend({
  updateId: function(record, data) {
    var oldId = Ember.get(record, 'id');
    var id = coerceId(data.id);

    if (oldId && oldId !== id) {
      this.typeMapFor(record.constructor).idToRecord[oldId] = record;
    } else {
      this.typeMapFor(record.constructor).idToRecord[id] = record;
    }

    Ember.set(record, 'id', id);
  },
};
```

But this just feels wrong. Are there any negative consequences to this override? Or is there any other way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

I would try and have a look at [unloadRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadRecord).
Make the `PUT` request. If it fails due to this error, unload the record and fetch it again and retry the `PUT`